# Cross-country car rental

Tags: car-rentals

I intend to rent a car at either Berlin or Prague, and drive across Poland, Lithuania and Latvia. I will return the car to the original country of hire. The rental period will be about 10 days.

Are there any first hand experienced travelers here who can give me their 2-cents? Is it allowed and if yes, how much will be the additional charges?

My preference is to rent from one of the bigger players (Avis / Europcar / Hertz / SixT). I have greater comfort with them and thanks to my credit card and airlines memberships I get benefits too.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't ask your rental company of choice? Do you think random people on the internets know their current policies better?

Comment: Umm, why do you assume I *haven't* emailed them already?

Comment: If only you had read my question properly, it clearly states "Are there any first hand experienced travelers here who can give me their 2-cents?" I am looking for real experiences because policies vary between countries and companies and membership levels.

For example, I have rented in Germany and driven to France and Italy (two separate occassions, two separate rental companies). I was charged both times but one company had a condition according to the category of the car rented. I am looking for such examples. Hope this is clearer to you now?

Comment: We only know you did something if you told us. We are not mind readers or the NSA. It might be helpful if we were! Though I also don't understand why, if you want to know how much are rental company charges and conditions, you are not asking the rental company!

Comment: @TheYoungMunk Your question isn't really suited to this site. Questions about comparing prices between different companies are off-topic because they quickly go out of date. "Can you give me your 2-cents?" is an invitation to a discussion, not an objectively answerable question.

Comment: Please do not delete or neutralize your questions when they go on hold. You agreed to leave the text online when you posted it.

Answer (score 4):

When I checked last, *none* of the larger car rental agencies in all of western Europe allows their cars being taking in the eastern countries you listed (and small ones typically don't allow any border crossings at all)

If this is unchanged, you will not find anyone with such experience.

Comment: All these countries are a part of EU. It looks like we are still behind Iron Curtain :(

Comment: Yep, as long as car theft rates are high, they will not allow it.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the terms of conditions of all the bigger players on their websites. I just did for [AVIS](https://www.avis.ch/TermsAndCondition) and selected Germany as the country of origin:

> Entries into Czech Republic (CZ), Croatia (HR), Hungary (H), Poland (PL), Slovakia (SK) and Slovenia (SLO) are only allowed for vehicles up to medium class and not allowed for vehicles of the makes Audi, BMW, Jaguar, Land Rover, Mercedes Benz and Volkswagen.
>
> Entries to Italy (I), Southern France (F) and San Marino (RSM) are only allowed for vehicles up to executive class.
>
> Porsche vehicles may be driven in Germany (D), Austria (A0 and Switzerland (CH) only.
>
> You are not allowed to use the vehicle in Albania (AL), Azerbaijan (AZ), Bulgaria (BG), Bosnia and Herzegovina (HIB), Belarus (BY), Cyprus (CY), Estonia (EST), Georgia (GE), Greece (GR), Iceland (IS), Kazakhstan (KZ), Latvia (LV), Lithuania (LT), Malta (M), Macedonia (MK), Moldovia (MD), Montenegro (MNE), Romania (RO), Russia (RUS), Serbia (SRB), Turkey (TR), Ukraine (UA) and any country outside continental Europe.
>
> **Can I buy a product to allow me to drive in other countries?**
>
> No, regrettably, we do not offer any products that allow you to drive in other countries.

I assume similar rules are in place with the other bigger rental companies

Comment: Pleae don't include screenshots of text. It can't be searched and it's inaccessible to screen readers. Copy-paste avoids both of these problems -- and is easier to do!

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm fully aware of that. Unfortunately the source was a PDF document which didn't allow copy/paste of text (if I remember correctly it was image-only).

Comment: Ah, OK -- that wasn't obvious from your answer (and I didn't follow the link)